# Flexible widgets not rendering inside Column

Tags: flutter

I need to word-wrap some text and have been reading how Flexible and Expanded help make that happen. My problem is the rendering breaks when I put the resulting widgets in a Column. I read that you need to wrap parent columns in Expanded widgets, too, but that gave the same broken result?

Here's a text version of what I'm after

[image]

The DartPad code below produces that, but when the commented Column is uncommented, no text is rendered?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeDat.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child: MyWidget(),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // Column( children: [     // <- Uncommenting Column breaks rendering
        Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
        Text('[Avatar]'),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Flexible(
            child: Text(
                'Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really '
                'Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Heading'),
            ),
            Flexible(
            child: Text(
                'Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really '
                'Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Text'),
            ),
        ]),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Text('[Button]'),
        // ]),
    ],
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue just by wrapping the `Row` with an `Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Flexible(fit: FlexFit.loose,child:.....)
```